# Custom Button in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I have defined several command line tools in PhpStorm.

Is there a way to create custom buttons for calling this scripts?

I can't find any settings for this in the preferences panel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create command and check all in `Show in` section. You can find your command in menu `Tools -> External Tools -> Test Command`

But i prefer to assign hotkey =)

[image: phpstorm custom command configuration]

Links:

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+External+Tools+in+PhpStorm

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/external-tools.html

Answer (score 3):

1. Create your custom command in `Tools -> External Tools -> Test Command`
2. Create button in `Appearance & Behavior -> Menus and Toolbars -> Main Toolbar -> Toolbar Run Actions` with link to created command.
3. Enjoy!